# Cannot write CIE's IEEE address to IAS zone device

Tags: zigbee

I am using trying to add the following IAS zone devices (from HEIMAN) to my ZCL co-ordinator(CIE) + IoT gateway (from NXP)

1. emergency button - gets added easily and triggers successfully

[image]

2. door sensor - joins the network but no enrolment process is seen

[image]

Q1. Why is it such that one device undergoes enrolment process correctly and the other doesn't? My understanding is that the ZCL stack should do all the enrolment activities. Am I correct?

Q2. I tried writing IEEE address of the CIE to the node's cluster(0x0500) attribute (0x0010) of attribute type (0xf0). But no response. How to tackle this issue?

Answer (score 0):

For a CIE device, the enrolment is more complex and the ZCL stack will not perform this for you (although this may depend on the stack, and any add-on features it provides).

A CIE device may perform its own service discovery using the ZDO Match Descriptor functions. It may send a `MatchDescriptorRequest` report looking for an IAS server, and you will need to respond with the `MatchDescriptorResponse` to report that you support this. Typically the request will be looking for the IAS Zone Server cluster (0x500), but you should inspect the packets and respond appropriately. See 2.4.3.1.7 Match_Desc_req, and 2.4.4.1.7 Match_Desc_rsp of the ZigBee specification. If an IAS device is looking for a zone controller, it *may* not accept any requests until it receives this response, and in fact some devices may leave the network if they don't find the services they are requesting.

Next, it may enrol with the IAS service by sending the `ZoneEnrollRequest` command, and your application will need to respond to this with the `ZoneEnrollResponse` to tell the device that it is now enrolled in your system. Refer to 8.2.2.4.2 Zone Enroll Request Command in the ZCL specification.

From your traces, it is hard to say what is happening as the log viewer doesn't provide any information on the contents of the Data Request frames in this view. However, we can see a lot of frames being sent from the device to the coordinator, and it is likely that it is performing one, or both of the discovery services discussed above. You should inspect the requests to find out what they are, and check the appropriate sections of the ZigBee specification, or the ZigBee Cluster Library Specification.

Comment: In the the first sniffer log it is seen that both the CIE and IAS zone button  sends MatchDescRequest to each other. Who should initiate this first?

Answer (score 0):

CIE IEEE Address to IAS zone worked successfully. Tested using Xbee s2c.

```
Explicit Addressing Command Frame (API 2)

7E 00 22 7D 31 01 28 6D 97 00 01 04 2B 7D 5D FF FE E8 01 05 00 01 04 00 20 00 01 02 10 00 F0 6B 7A 29 41 00 A2 7D 33 00 FD

Start delimiter: 7E
Length: 00 22 (34)
Frame type: 11 (Explicit Addressing Command Frame)
Frame ID: 01 (1)
64-bit dest. address: 28 6D 97 00 01 04 2B 7D
16-bit dest. address: FF FE
Source endpoint: E8
Dest. endpoint: 01
Cluster ID: 05 00
Profile ID: 01 04
Broadcast radius: 00 (0)
Transmit options: 20
RF data: 00 01 02 10 00 F0 6B 7A 29 41 00 A2 13 00
Checksum: FD

Explicit RX Indicator (API 2)

7E 00 16 91 28 6D 97 00 01 04 2B 7D 5D A3 87 01 E8 05 00 01 04 21 18 01 04 00 3A

Start delimiter: 7E
Length: 00 16 (22)
Frame type: 91 (Explicit RX Indicator)
64-bit source address: 28 6D 97 00 01 04 2B 7D
16-bit source address: A3 87
Source endpoint: 01
Destination endpoint: E8
Cluster ID: 05 00
Profile ID: 01 04
Receive options: 21
RF data: 18 01 04 00
Checksum: 3A
```